# The function avformat_open_input from ffmpeg lib cann't open file

Tags: visual-c++, ffmpeg

I'm tried open file from my code with ffmpeg lib. And avformat_open_input always receive an error "No such file or directory". I tried different files and directories but results are the same.

I use VS 2010 on Win7 and compiled lib and dll from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

A bit of my code.

```
int decode_sound(const char * infile, const char * outfile) 
{
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = 0;
    if((err = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, infile, NULL, 0)) != 0)
       return 1;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    avcodec_register_all();

    cout << decode_sound("D:\\DELTA.MPG", "D:\\wav.wav") << endl;

    char errbuf[128];
    const char *errbuf_ptr = errbuf;
    if (av_strerror(err, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf)) < 0)
          strerror_s(errbuf, AVUNERROR(err));
    cout << err << endl << errbuf_ptr << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a kind of old question, but this

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

is your problem. Windows is passing in a wide charachter string and you are casting it to a char string so ffmpeg is only seeing the first byte of it.  Changing that to

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Will fix it